# neatly pack items into a rectangular box

Tags: html, css, grid-layout

I can't think of a more elegant way to explain this. So I have a rectangular container and a variable number of items and I want to fill the container evenly like so

if the aspect ratio of the container is `1.5` and I have `6` items, columns should probably be `3`

```
x x x
x x x
```

if the aspect ratio of the container is `2.0` and I have `32` items, columns should probably be `8`

```
x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x
```

if by chance the ratio is `2.0` and I have `30` items, columns should probably still be `8`

```
x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x
```

and so on. I feel like this should be simple but I can't think of a simple way to do it. the input would be `items`, `width`, and `height`, and the output would be `columns` (rows would fill out themselves)

thanks

Comment: despite someone else's tags, this isn't an html or css question

Comment: Okay.. sorry... you're not going to get many people seeing your post with only `grid-layout`... You should add some more relevant tags (and remove the ones I put in)..

Comment: It's not a programming question either, so add relevant tags yourself.

Comment: I could've added `javascript` but this isn't specific to javascript and that wouldn't have explained anything. I don't know of anything besides programming that accepts arguments and returns a value so I just assumed given the arguments in op and the desired output and asking on SO that it would be a given I'm looking for a language nonspecific formula. maybe it would've been better to ask on math.se but I'm just here to find help not navigate a whole other maze. besides, someone who understood the question gave me the answer I needed, which used to be what was important here.

Comment: If you disagree with an edit, you can roll it back. I'm not sure which tags should go here - it's really about which algorithm to use. But the "algorithm" tag itself is a bit of a meta-tag. The question is indeed not specific to HTML or CSS, let alone CSS3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula I got is sqrt(items/aspect_ratio) * aspect_ratio. You can round this result up to get the desired result in scenario 3.

How I got it:

```
'aspect ratio just seems to be scale of the number of rows; as such 
columns = rows * aspect ratio
also 
items = rows * columns 
now subbing in / algebra
rows^2 * aspect ratio = items
rows = sqrt(items/aspect ration)
columns = sqrt(items/ aspect ratio) * aspect ratio'
```